# Any ideas on how to implement a 'touchMoveOver' event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ipad, svg

I'm faffing around with SVG, specifically for web content aimed at iPad users. I've created a little dial type thingy that I'm calling a "cheese board" that I'd like to use as an interface element.

http://appliedworks.co.uk/files/times/SVGTests/raphael.html

Clicking on a piece of cheese (to keep the analogy going) will do "something". That bit's easy. However, I'd like the user to be able to drag their finger around the 'cheese board', firing a new event (touchesMovedOver?) every time they their finger moves over a new piece of cheese. But I can't figure out how to do it since there's no 'mouseOver' equivalent for touch interfaces.

If the whole thing was made of squares, I could have created some sort of 'rectContainsPoint' method to be called for every 'touchesMoved', but that approach wouldn't work here.

If anyone has any idea about how something like this could be achieved, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

I also don't know what happens inside SVG, but I think you should be able to implement it using the "touchmove" event. The Safari Reference Library has a good article about iphone/ipad touch events: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how they extend into SVG, but there are definitely methods for handling touch events with JavaScript: http://rossboucher.com/2008/08/19/iphone-touch-events-in-javascript/

Comment: this much I know, but there's no touchMovedOver event to replace the mouseOver event. Since users are expected to drag their fingers around the screen, it feels like this is an event that should exist.

Comment: I believe that SVG has a function for getting elements of the SVG graphic below a given coordinate. Coupling this ability with the location of the finger as provided by the iPhone's touch event API you should be able to figure out which elements are `mouseover`'d and `mouseout`'d and dispatch these events yourself. This sounds like a really interesting problem to tackle. Send me an iPhone and I'll try and work it out for you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right that there is no equivalent of the mouseover event for SVG. Check out this think piece by a Flash developer who [opines on the sad situation](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/08/iphone_events.html).

> the iPhone doesn’t do mouse movement,
>   and if you can’t move the mouse
>   between the mousedown and mouseup
>   events, the difference between mouseup
>   and click becomes meaningless.
>
> Mousedown, in theory, still has a
>   valid function as a separate event
>   that’s fired when the user touches the
>   screen—regardless of what happens
>   later. Unfortunately for theory,
>   that’s not the way it works on the
>   iPhone.
>
> When you touch an element and leave
>   your finger in place for a while, you
>   get the option of de-focusing it (i.e.
>   you’re allowed to state you don’t want
>   to follow this link after all). In
>   JavaScript event terms, I’d expected a
>   mousedown event to fire, but not a
>   click (I was uncertain of mouseup).
>   Instead, no event fires.